# Paypal pasarela integral spanish to french?

Tags: paypal, localization

I have Paypal pasarela Integral Evolution (spanish version of Paypal pro), so far the only languages available are spanish OR english, the tech support told me it's because my account is in Spain and that if I want Paypal integral in other languages I must open a Paypal account in every single countries I am interested in.

This doesn't make sense, i can't open xxx Paypal AND bank account all over Europe just to get a payment form in more languages, this is very weird as Express checkout comes in several differents languages with my spanish paypal account.

My question is:

Is there a way to bypass this spanish/english only and have french text for Pasarela integral evolution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Simple answer: it's not possible to change language with integral evolution.

Really astonishing and stupid. If you sell enough products / services, I suggest you to talk to your bank, which is usually cheaper and has better customization options, even if sometimes more complicated to integrate in your website